# FullText Search Innodb Fails, MyIsam Returns Results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, myisam, mysql-5.6

I've upgraded a table from `myisam` to `innodb` but am not having the same performance. The `innodb` returns a `0` score when there should be some relation. The `myisam` table returns a match for the same term (I kept a copy of the old table so I can still run the same query).

```
SELECT MATCH (COLUMNS) AGAINST ('+"Term Ex"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
FROM table_myisam
where id = 1;
```

Returns:

```
+-------+
| score |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
```

but:

```
SELECT MATCH (COLUMNS) AGAINST ('+"Term Ex"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
FROM table
where id = 1;
```

returns:

```
+-------+
| score |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

I thought the `ex` might not have been indexed because `innodb_ft_min_token_size` was set to `3`. I lowered that to `1` and optimized the table but that had no affect. The column contents are 99 characters long so I presumed the whole column wasn't indexed because of `innodb_ft_max_token_size`. I increased that as well to `150` and ran the optimize again but again had the same result.

The only difference between these tables is the engine and the character set. This table is using `utf8`, the `myisam` table is using `latin1`.

Has anyone seen these behavior, or have advice for how to resolve it?

**UPDATE:**
I added `ft_stopword_file=""` to my `my.cnf` and ran `OPTIMIZE TABLE table` again. This time I got

> optimize | note | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead

The query worked after this change. `Ex` is not a stop word though so not sure why it would make a difference.

A new query that fails though is:

```
SELECT MATCH (Columns) AGAINST ('+Term +Ex +in' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score FROM Table where id = 1;

+-------+
| score |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

the `in` causes this to fail but that is the next word in my table.

```
SELECT MATCH (Columns) AGAINST ('+Term +Ex' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score FROM Table where id = 1;

+--------------------+
| score              |
+--------------------+
| 219.30206298828125 |
+--------------------+
```

I also tried `CREATE TABLE my_stopwords(value VARCHAR(30)) ENGINE = INNODB;`, then updated `my.cnf` with `innodb_ft_server_stopword_table='db/my_stopwords'`. I restarted and ran:

```
show variables like 'innodb_ft_server_stopword_table';
```

which brought back:

```
+---------------------------------+---------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                     |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------+
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table | 'db/my_stopwords'; |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------+
```

so I thought the `in` would not cause the query to fail now but it continues. I also tried `OPTIMIZE TABLE table` again and even `ALTER TABLE table DROP INDEX ...`  and `ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT KEY ...` none of which have had an affect.

**Second Update**
The issue is with the stop words.

```
$userinput = preg_replace('/\b(a|about|an|are|as|at|be|by|com|de|en|for|from|how|i|in|is|it|la|of|on|or|that|the|this|to|was|what|when|where|who|will|with|und|the|www)\b/', '', $userinput);
```

resolves the issue but that doesn't appear as a good solution to me. I'd like a solution that avoids the stop words breaking this in mysql.

**Stopword table data:**

```
CREATE TABLE `my_stopwords` (
  `value` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and

```
Name: my_stopwords
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 0
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2019-04-09 17:39:55
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment:
```

Comment: Please also post the value of `columns` (or values - if it's a composite index).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It is a list of 14 columns. Should I add that, or just add a `create table` statement?

Comment: You don't need 14 columns to reproduce the issue. Create an example table with two rows, two columns and the values, which have the same issue.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I think these demonstrate the issue. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t9iXPrxq1ZwPa6CPzdiL6M/2 https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t9iXPrxq1ZwPa6CPzdiL6M/3

Comment: You can't demonstrate it on DB-fiddle, since you cannot overwrite global or read-only variables. I've tested it on my local machine with v5.6.21 - and couldn't reproduce your issue. I've got a non-zero value for "+Term +Ex +In". So that's why I asked to create an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK.. You can actually overwrite a global variable on db-fiddle - But [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pHFaCD5YCpSEgXAo4F3vJQ/0) I was able to use a stop word ("with").

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `in` still fails to match on that example though so I think that is reproducible. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pHFaCD5YCpSEgXAo4F3vJQ/2 I can't modify the full text innodbs on that server though.

Comment: You wrote, that you have fixed the problem with `innodb_ft_min_token_size` since `+Ex` works for you. As I understand you - The only issue is with `+In`. And since `+Ex` works, the issue must be with stop words. But I've demonstrated, that it's possible to work with stop words. So again - I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That was my presumption. I'm open to any/all suggestions. `A` also broke my search e.g. `+A +Term +Ex` so only stop words cause my search to fail. It is consistent across 2 slaves and the master DB. It is running a Percona instance of `5.6.41-84.1` if that makes a difference

Comment: Did you try with longer stop words like `with` or  `where`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes, a search for `AGAINST ('+with' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` brings back 0 results. A`select count(*) from table where concat(columns) like '%with%';` brings back 10468.

Comment: In your first Update, what was the text that you were hoping to match?

Comment: @RickJames `Term Ex` was the first term i tried to match. Decreasing the length resolved that. `Term Ex in` then failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several differences between MyISAM's FULLTEXT and InnoDB's.  I think you were caught by the handling of 'short' words and/or stop words.  MyISAM will show rows, but InnoDB will fail to.

What I have done when using FT (and after switching to InnoDB) is to filter the user's input to avoid short words.  It takes extra effort but gets me the rows desired.  My case is slightly different since the resulting query is something like this.  Note that I have added `+` to require the words, but not on words shorter than 3 (my `ft_min_token_size` is 3).  These searches were for `build a table` and `build the table`:

```
WHERE match(description) AGAINST('+build* a +table*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
WHERE match(description) AGAINST('+build* +the* +table*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

(The trailing `*` may be redundant; I have not investigated that.)

**Another approach**

Since FT is very efficient at non-short, non-stop words, do the search with two phases, each being optional:  To search for "a long word", do

```
WHERE MATCH(d) AGAINST ('+long +word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND d REGEXP '[[:<:]]a[[:>:]]'
```

The first part whittles down the possible rows rapidly by looking for 'long' and 'word' (as *words*).  The second part makes sure there is a *word* `a` in the string, too.  The `REGEXP` is costly but will be applied only to those rows that pass the first test.

To search *just* for "long word":

```
WHERE MATCH(d) AGAINST ('+long +word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

To search *just* for the word "a":

```
WHERE d REGEXP '[[:<:]]a[[:>:]]'
```

Caveat:  This case will be slow.

Note:  My examples allow for the words to be in any order, and in any location in the string.  That is, this string will match in all my examples:  "She was longing for a word from him."

Comment: This is what my research has also yielded. There is no way to make the `a` stop word become a non-stop word though? I want it indexed. I'm using a similiar solution now with a regex to construct the query string but i'd prefer to just pass it all in with the `+`s on every term. My search rules are that all entered terms must be present.

Comment: @user3783243 - There is no "perfect" solution to what you desire.  I added to my Answer a workaround that may be the 'best' solution.  Note how it requires constructing the `WHERE` clause based on the word(s) encountered, and might necessitate knowing the list of stop words.

Comment: That is true but the regexp will perform without an index, and without relevancy.

Comment: Again, no 'perfect' solution.

Comment: So there is no way to ignore the stops words though? That seems like the perfect solution and `myisam` offered that. It seems like `innodb` took a step backwards in that regard to me. I am just beginning to us `innodb` though so would like to confirm this is correct. From the manual and other SO threads it seems like a custom table is possible.

Comment: @user3783243 - I think there is a way to provide a custom stopword list file (that could be empty), but I don't have the details.

Comment: I looked at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_server_stopword_table and followed the directives there as well as the 8.0 version but neither worked for me.

Comment: @user3783243 - I suspect there is a simple mistake somewhere...  You did rebuild the FT index on your table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for your stopword table.

Comment: Data added to the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step procedure which should have reproduced your problem. (This is actually how you should have written your question.) The environment is a freshly installed VM with *Debian 9.8* and *Percona Server Ver 5.6.43-84.3*.

1. Create an *InnoDB* table with a *fulltext index* and some dummy data:

   ```
   create table test.ft_innodb (
       txt text,
       fulltext index (txt)
   ) engine=innodb charset=utf8 collate=utf8_unicode_ci;

   insert into test.ft_innodb (txt) values
       ('Some dummy text'),
       ('Text with a long and short stop words in it ex');
   ```
2. Execute a test query to verify that it doesn't work yet as we need:

   ```
   select txt
       , match(t.txt) against ('+some' in boolean mode) as score0
       , match(t.txt) against ('+with' in boolean mode) as score1
       , match(t.txt) against ('+in'   in boolean mode) as score2
       , match(t.txt) against ('+ex'   in boolean mode) as score3
   from test.ft_innodb t;
   ```

   Result (rounded):

   ```
   txt                                            | score0 | score1 | score2 | score3
   -----------------------------------------------|--------|--------|--------|-------
   Some dummy text                                | 0.0906 | 0      | 0      | 0
   Text with a long and short stop words in it ex | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0
   ```

   As you see, it's not working with stop words ("+with") or with short words ("+ex").
3. Create an empty *InnoDB* table for custom stop words:

   ```
   create table test.my_stopwords (value varchar(30)) engine=innodb;
   ```
4. Edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and add the following two lines in the `[mysqld]` block:

   ```
   [mysqld]
   # other settings
   innodb_ft_server_stopword_table = "test/my_stopwords"
   innodb_ft_min_token_size = 1
   ```
5. Restart MySQL with `service mysql restart`
6. Run the query from (2.) again (The result should be the same)
7. Rebuild the *fulltext index* with

   ```
   optimize table test.ft_innodb;
   ```

   It will actually rebuild the entire tabe including all indexes.
8. Execute the test query from (2.) again. Now the result is:

   ```
   txt                                            | score1 | score1 | score2 | score3
   -----------------------------------------------|--------|--------|--------|-------
   Some dummy text                                | 0.0906 | 0      | 0      | 0
   Text with a long and short stop words in it ex | 0      | 0.0906 | 0.0906 | 0.0906
   ```

You see it works just fine for me. And it's quite simple to reproduce. (Again - This is how you should have written your question.)

Since your procedure is rather chaotic than detailed, it's difficult to say what could go wrong for you. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_stopwords(value VARCHAR(30)) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

This doesn't contain the information, in which database you have defined that table. Note that I have prefixed all my tables with the corresponding database. Now consider the following: I change `my.cnf` and set `innodb_ft_server_stopword_table = "db/my_stopwords"`. Note - There is no such table on my server (not even the schema `db` exists). Restart the MySQL server. And check the new settings with

```
show variables like 'innodb_ft_server_stopword_table';
```

This returns:

```
    Variable_name                   | Value
    --------------------------------|----------------
    innodb_ft_server_stopword_table | db/my_stopwords
```

And after `optimize table test.ft_innodb;` the test query returns this:

```
    txt                                            | score0 | score1 | score2 | score3
    -----------------------------------------------|--------|--------|--------|-------
    Some dummy text                                | 0.0906 | 0      | 0      | 0
    Text with a long and short stop words in it ex | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0.0906
```

You see? It's not working with stopwords any more. But it works with short non stop words like "+ex". So make sure, that the table you defined in `innodb_ft_server_stopword_table` actually exists.

Comment: The table existed without the fully qualified statement. It used the DB i was already in. Running step 3 produced `ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'my_stopwords' already exists`. Step 2 also brought back a score for `score3` (because I'd already reduced the index length I'd guess).  Step 8 resulted in the same return.

Comment: "It used the DB i was already in" - And what's the name of the DB? `db`?

Comment: In the example yes, `db` is the database name. I use `use db;` prior to the query executions.

Comment: Nicely written Question!

Answer (score 0):

A common technique in searching is to make an extra column with the 'sanitized' string to search in.  Then add the FULLTEXT index to that column instead of the original column.

In your case, removing the stopwords is the main difference.  But there may also be punctuation that could (should?) be removed.  Sometimes hyphenated words or words or contractions or part numbers or model numbers cause trouble.  They can be modified to change the punctuation or spacing to make it more friendly with the FT requirements and/or the user's flavor of input.  Another thing is to add words to the search-string column that are common misspellings of the words that are in the column.

Sure, this is more work than you would like to have to do.  But I think it provides a viable solution.